# Joomla - not found на всех ссылках

Tags: joomla

Здравствуйте! Может кто то встречался с такой проблемой... В пунктах меню, на joomle, все ссылки, кроме главной страницы, не работают... В чем может быть причина?

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если версия Joomla 1.5.X, то:
а) Инструменты->Очистить кэш->Проверить работу ссылок
б) Сайт->Общие настройки->Включить SEO->Нет->Проверить работу ссылок
Если версия Joomla 1.7.X или 2.5.X, то:
а) Инструменты->Очистить кэш->Проверить работу ссылок
б) Все меню->Проблемное меню->Перестроить(или как-то так)->Проверить работу ссылок